# How do I build an app on an Android platform that uses Google Input functionality?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm creating an external app for a company and would like to use the Google Input functionality for Android users. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you could use endpoints to interface from android to backend appengine

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/